# How do I combine multiple rows into one using R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that contains data about patients. Some patients have multiple rows and I want to combine these rows, so that each patient has one row.

I have about 20 different variables. Some variables need to stay the same when combining rows (e.g., a patient with 4 rows that is in group 1, should still be in group 1 when the rows are combined), but I have also variables that have to meet a certain condition (e.g., if a patient had surgery in one (or multiple) of the rows, it should become a 'yes'. If not, it should become a 'no').

I have tried searching for the answer, but I am confused. I tried using plyr, but it seems that using this function is not recommended, as it becomes slow with very large datasets. I have found some information about dplyr, but I am not understanding how I should use this.

So for example, I have the following dataset (my apologies for how I present this, I am new to Stackoverflow)

```
**Patient_Id** /**Group** /**Age** /**Gender** /**surgery y/n** /**no of surgeries** 

1 - 1 - 63 - F - no - 0      

1 - 1 - 63 - F - no - 0

1 - 1 - 64 - F - yes - 1

2 - 0 - 60 - M - yes - 2

3 - 1 - 65 - M - no - 0

4 - 0 - 60 - F - no - 0

4 - 0 - 61 - F - yes - 1

4 - 0 - 62 - F - yes - 1
```

And I want to make a dataframe like this

```
**Patient_Id** /**Group** /**Age** /**Gender** /**surgery y/n** /**no of surgeries** 

1 - 1 - 63,33 - F - yes - 1 

2 - 0 - 60 - M - yes - 2

3 - 1 - 65 - M - no - 0

4 - 0 - 61 - F - yes - 2
```

Does anyone know what function would be best to use? Or how to start?
Thank you in advance!

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Patient_Id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4), 
Group = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Age = c(63, 63, 64, 
60, 65, 60, 61, 62), Gender = c("F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F"), `surgery y/n` = c("no", "no", "yes", 
"yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"), `no of surgeries` = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
class = "data.frame")


df2 <-
structure(list(Patient_Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
Group = c(1, 0, 1, 0), Age = c("63,33", 
"60", "65", "61"), Gender = c("F", "M", 
"M", "F"), `surgery y/n` = c("yes", "yes", 
"no", "yes"), `no of surgeries` = c(1, 2, 
0, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

The structure of my dataframe is as followed:

str( SMARTdata_50j_diagc_2016 )
'data.frame':   458794 obs. of  20 variables:

$ Groep                      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...

$ Ziekenhuis_Nr              : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","10","11",..: 2 8 4 11 3 7 10 9 13 6 ...

$ Ziekenhuistype             : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 ...

$ Patient_Id                 : num  85550 101414 239946 291650 140558 ...

$ DBC_Id                     : num  181394 230887 448945 524873 251352 ...

$ Diagnose_Code              : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ Zorgtype_Code              : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...

$ Lft_patient_openenDBC      : num  50 80 66 60 67 64 54 71 70 76 ...

$ Geslacht                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...

$ MRI_nee_ja                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ MRI_Aantal                 : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

$ Artroscopie_nee_jaz_jam    : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ Artroscopie_aantal         : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

$ Jaar_openen_DBC            : num  2016 2017 2018 2017 2017 ...

$ Mnd_openen_DBC             : num  12 5 6 2 5 8 10 11 1 1 ...

$ Jaar_sluiten_DBC           : num  2017 2017 2018 2017 2017 ...

$ Mnd_sluiten_DBC            : num  4 9 10 4 9 12 2 3 4 5 ...

$ Aantal_overigeDBC_bijopenen: num  1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...

$ open_DBC                   : 'yearmon' num  Dec 2016 May 2017 Jun 2018 Feb 2017 ...

$ sluiten_DBC                : 'yearmon' num  Apr 2017 Sep 2017 Oct 2018 Apr 2017 ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: For a better understanding of the question, please make a reproducible example.

Comment: @Diego, my apologies! I hope my edit makes it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is straight forward. One way to do it via `dplyr` package would be,

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
 group_by(Patient_Id) %>% 
 summarise(Group = first(Group), 
           Age = mean(Age), 
           Gender = first(Gender), 
           `no of surgeries` = sum(`no of surgeries`), 
          `surgery y/n` = ifelse(`no of surgeries` == 0, 'no', 'yes'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 6
>   Patient_Id Group   Age Gender `no of surgeries` `surgery y/n`
>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <int> <chr>        
> 1          1     1  63.3 F                      1 yes          
> 2          2     0  60   M                      2 yes          
> 3          3     1  65   M                      0 no           
> 4          4     0  61   F                      2 yes
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried what you suggested (also before), but the problem is that I get a dataframe with only one observation! I tried running exactly what you wrote on my dataset, but I get the following error: Error in quicker(.data[names(cols)]): length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your data frame? Do `str(your_data_frame)` and post it in your question

Comment: I've added the structure of the data frame. I think it's a 'normal' data frame, I cannot see what could be wrong with it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I figured it out!